# Eclipse crashed, works space now can't be opened, and importing the projects wont work either

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Eclipse crashed, works space now can't be opened, and importing the projects wont work either. That about explains it all right there.

Creating a new workspace, I still cant import any of the projects. It acts like it is about to, but then nothing.

Any ideas? Not all of the projects are on svn.

Here are some of the errors i see in the crash reports

> The file has been changed on disk, and it now contains invalid information.  The project will not function properly until the description file is restored to a valid state.
>
> Premature end of file.
>
> does not exist

and the message that appeared before it all crashed and burned

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

**NEW INFO**

every single file in every single on of my projects, now has a size of 0kb. all the files exist, but every .png, .jpg .class .xml is empty with a size of 0kb

Comment: Have you tried to reset the workspace configurations? http://breathingtech.com/2009/how-to-reset-workspace-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try editing eclipse.ini file.

put `put -Xms512m -Xmx1024m`

then try to restart eclipse it should work!!

Comment: I imagine this would have worked, but the proble runs much deeper, see my new edit above

Comment: upvoted because i ended up doing this, and set it to  -vmargs -Xms2048m -Xmx2560m, there was no fixing what had already hapened, but this seems to help eclipse overall

Comment: Hey In that case you can restore all files from eclipse history, give a try to that!!

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-87b.htm

Answer (score 0):

Can you install a second instance of Eclipse and point it at the workspace? I've done this with the ADT on my mac before.

Comment: FWIW I have done this successfully with non-ADT projects as well.

Comment: the install program just "unzips" the eclipse program into a directory. no need to uninstall (win or linux)

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar trouble with corrupted workspaces in the past.  They don't load even in a fresh copy of Eclipse.

What has helped me is deleting/renaming file `myWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap`

Sometimes also deleting `*.snap` files.

Please backup the whole workspace (including projects) first!

Comment: couldnt find that file, but I dont think that will help me here, though I thank you for the help. All the work i have done today is lost, I just have to accept it. Eclipse somehow corrupted every project's resources and classes to the point they now have a size of o kb, meaning they are gone for good.

Answer (score 0):

Close eclipse.
Copy your wanted project files (ie. workspace\Homework) to a temp directory, not the entire workspace.
Start eclipse.
Create a new workspace (you stated you could).
Delete the old workspace (might be able to this before previous step).
Import project from temp directory into new workspace.
Save!
Close and re-open eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The "NEW INFO" section makes it look like you are out of disk space on the system. Have you checked?

Comment: I am running a 500+GB SSD, 16GB DDR3 RAM, 2.7GHz i-7 (w/ turboboost to 3.7) and 1GB GDDR5 NVIDIA graphics. My SSD has 80% memory unused. I wish it was that simple :( I went in and configured eclipse to use 2GB RAM now. It seems to be running a little better. This project is someone elses that I inherited and it is all sorts of ugly.