# Eclipse crashed and now I can't access my workspace. Eclipse deleted my files after the crash. How is that a solution to anything?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Eclipse crashed and now I can't access my workspace. I can't even edit the files in a notepad app. I tried deleting the .metadate the .lock file. Tried restarting even the computer. Nothing worked. Is my project lost now? Oh I just looked and my src folder has 0bytes. How is it possible? Should I take it as a sign that I should change to android studio or is that just as buggy?

Answer (score 0):

what about your project in your workspace? I mean in your hardDrive.the root of your project still there.just look at it.

Comment: Yeah it seems odd that Eclipse would completely remove it due to a crash.. Unless something else removed it, which in turn made eclipse crash, but that's equally unlikely

Comment: I did look at it and the src files are empty. I can't open them with  any word editor. They have 0 bytes and won't open.

Comment: This guy seems to have had the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391415/eclipse-crashed-works-space-now-cant-be-opened-and-importing-the-projects-won